# Login info from keycloak event

Tags: java, events, keycloak

Is it possible to receive an *event* from `keycloak` regarding the login/logout of a user in java code? if so, how can I do this? which classes or interfaces are responsible for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Events located in Keycloak.

After successfully logging into your selected realm (by default Master Realm), you will be able to locate the Events in the Left Hand Side Menu bar.

[image]

After navigating to the Events Menu, you can see Login Events, Admin Events  and Config tabs.

[image]

By default “Save Events” is set to OFF.

**Login Events Settings**

After enabling “Save Events”, you will see lots of event categories from which you can select.

select the events which you looking for and after doing the above steps, click on “Save” to persist our settings in Keycloak. Next, logout of the Admin Console and then try login again. Go to Events Menu on the Left Hand Side and you will be landed on Login Events